# C# - Xml manipulation using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

In C#, how do I replace a node in an xml with another node using XmlDocument.

For E.g, consider the following xml file.

```
<Products>
  <Product ProdID="1">
    <Data>abc</Data>
  </Product>
  <Product ProdID="2">
    <Data>def</Data>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

Let us say I need to replace

```
  <Product ProdID="2">
    <Data>def</Data>
  </Product>
```

with a new node

```
  <Product ProdID="2">
    <Data>xyz</Data>
  </Product>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to locate the XmlElement to be replaced in the original XmlDocument and have the new node ready as XmlNode. Then you can call [ReplaceChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.replacechild.aspx) to replace the old node with the new node.

```
XmlNode product2 = document.SelectSingleNode(...);
XmlNode newNode = document.CreateElement(...);

product2.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newNode, product2);
```

If you just want to change the value of the Data tag, locate the node in the XmlDocument and set the [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value.aspx) property:

```
XmlNode data = document.SelectSingleNode(...);
data.Value = "xyz";
```